# Finding the content in the bracket rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have a variable called @gases that holds gas element such as Carbon Monoxide [CO], Carbon Dioxide [CO2]. Right now if someone searches CO in the search function Carbon Dioxide [CO2] shows up first. So I wanted to know if I could do something like this

```
where("(lower(gas_analytes.gas)\[.*?\]) LIKE lower(?)", "#{gas_analyte}")
```

so the code above, if someone only searches for the element and not the whole content, I used `\[.*?\]`, so if the search input equals the element in the bracket, but this does not work.

Is there anything similar I can do?

Answer (score 1):

I would probably just add the square brackets to the search pattern like this:

```
where("lower(gas_analytes.gas) LIKE ?", "%[#{gas_analyte.downcase}]%")
```

Note that if it is possible that `gas_analyze` might include `%` characters then you should sanitize that string before using it:

```
where("lower(gas_analytes.gas) LIKE ?", "%[#{sanitize_sql_like(gas_analyte.downcase)}]%")
```

Because `like` is very slow you might consider splitting the string and extracting the abbreviation into a database column on it own. That would improve the query time a lot.

Comment: @DLIM7 Please consider upvoting when an answer was helpful and accepting when it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for my (I'm using SQLite database):

```rb
# seeds.rb
# Type `rake db:seed` in terminal to run this file

# GasAnalyte.destroy_all

10.times do |t|
  GasAnalyte.create!(
    gas: "#{SecureRandom.uuid} [CO2]"
  )
end

p ['All', GasAnalyte.all].inspect

p ['Searching for "CO"', GasAnalyte.search_gas("CO")].inspect
```

```rb
# gas_analyte.rb
class GasAnalyte < ApplicationRecord
  validates :gas, presence: true

  scope :search_gas,
    ->(gas_analyte) { where("lower(gas_analytes.gas) LIKE lower(?)", "%[#{gas_analyte}%]") }
end
```

Here you can read about LIKE operator: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp